# NVIDIA Nouveau Driver: No more 3D acceleration?

Tags: compiz, nvidia, 3d, nouveau

After playing around with my drivers, my Nouveau driver no longer seems to support 3D acceleration: Compiz effects are gone, as are 3D gaming capabilities.

*Nouveau is still doing something correctly in 2D (e.g. the 1600x900 resolution is still correct, as compared to no NVIDIA driver at all, when it's 1280x768 instead).*

#### *How do I fix this without reinstall Ubuntu for the billionth time?*

---

xorg.conf's that I've tried:

- (empty)
- This (which was the original):

  ```
  Section "Device"
         Identifier      "Default Device"
         Driver  "nouveau"
  EndSection
  ```

Other things I've tried:

- `modprobe nouveau`
- `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau --remove`
- `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau --reinstall`
- Uninstalling/reinstalling through Additional Drivers

Comment: 1. Remove the xorg.conf file. 2. Please add the output of `ls -al /etc/alternatives/gl_conf`. 3. Do you have a file called `nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf` (or similar) in `/etc/modprobe.d`? 4. Are nvidia or nouveau in the output of`lsmod` after a boot?

Comment: 5. Did you recently update the system (like Xorg related packages)?6. Are you using any Xorg PPAs by any chance?

Comment: @htorque: 1. Done. 2. `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 2011-08-01 23:52 /etc/alternatives/gl_conf -> /usr/lib/mesa/ld.so.conf`. 3. No, I've removed that when uninstalling the proprietary driver. (nouveau **does start**, it's just that I don't get 3D acceleration anymore, just 2D graphics). 4. Yes, there are 5 entries that match `nouveau`. 5. No. 6. No. This thing was fine like 20 minutes before I fiddled around with the drivers, I didn't add/remove anything else during that time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fixed...

#### (But I'm not sure why!)

I followed [these instructions](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/X/Troubleshooting/NvidiaDriverSwitching#Problem:__Need_to_fully_remove_-nvidia_and_installing_or_reinstall_-nouveau_from_scratch) to reinstall the drivers, and rebooted.

Nothing changed.

*Then* I went into Additional Drivers and enabled Nouveau (which I'd already enabled and disabled numerous times, and which *should* have been enabled here)... and *then* I got 3D after I rebooted.